# KeyBoard Input JOGL

Tags: java, jogl, java-3d

I am using JOGL to render some models. I can implement the KeyListener interface and receive the keystrokes accordingly. But the problem is, I cannot refresh or render the model again after the key press. I can recieve the input but how do I clear the buffer again render it again after each key stroke in JOGL.

Comment: Can You show us the relevant code fragment?

Comment: [Input Class](http://pastebin.com/LDVn9apV)
[GLEventImplemeter Class](http://pastebin.com/BLkm1pwZ)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Add the jogl (`com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyListener`) keyListener, like [here](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle/blob/master/HelloTriangle/src/gl4/helloTriangle/HelloTriangle.java#L39).

Then play with these [two methods](https://github.com/elect86/helloTriangle/blob/master/HelloTriangle/src/gl4/helloTriangle/HelloTriangle.java#L326-L336)

Answer (score 0):

During the program load, init() > reshape() > display() methods are called respectively.Every reshape() method call, causes display() method to be executed as well.

In your case, apparently you are not calling display method on key event.You can either call display method  right after handling  user input or creating  an FPSAnimator class instance  for the canvas.When you start the animation by calling animator.start() display method will be called at a certain speed in background.Speed(fps) can also can be specified.
This link has a detailed explanation an samples  for your case.
https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-3

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Animator rather than FPSAnimator with my KeyListener canvas - I haven't quite figured out why (a lock on the surface, maybe?) but it wasn't updating the movements from my key press actions until a reshape call until I switched from the frame/second animator.